# stop Application Insight automatically installed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, azure-application-insights

I am using Visual Studio 2015. When I create an ASP.NET 4.6.1 Web API project, it starts very slow. I noticed the reason was visual studio automatically installed Application Insight as references. I looked up online and seemed like it's related to Azure and my company do not use Azure. How do I stop install Application Insight when I create a new web api project? Or maybe I do need that when I create Web API application?

Comment: as an fyi, it isn't "related to azure", that's just where it is exposed.  you don't need to host or deploy your web app in azure to take advantage of Application Insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't realize when I create a project, there's a checkbox on the right side of the dialog box says "Add Application Insights to project". I unchecked it and it worked.